# Currency symbols on pledge form

Tags: pledges, currency

The New Pledge Form has an option list for the available currencies set up in administration however the section on installments has the $ sign hard coded. If the pledge is in Thai Baht (THB), I want the baht symbol ฿ to be displayed. How can I change the form?